# twil python linux errors

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I've a raspberry PI whit raspbian. When i try to start a python application whit selenium it give me some errors.

This is the application:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/home/pi/Desktop/geckodriver')
```

This is errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uno.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/home/pi/Desktop/geckodriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

How can i fix?

Comment: Where did you get the `geckodriver`? Is it correct for the rPi platform? Try `file /home/pi/Desktop/geckodriver` to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

An `exec error` indicates you took the wrong OS file for geckodriver. See the below for all release

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

As of today (27th Jun 2018), you should probably be picking below

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.21.0/geckodriver-v0.21.0-arm7hf.tar.gz

Also make sure to do

```
chmod +x /home/pi/Desktop/geckodriver
```

So that it has executable rights